# Z transform causality

Tags: complex-analysis

$$\dfrac{z(z-1\cos a)}{ z^2-2z\cos a+1}$$

For this transform, I have
Zeros: $0, cos a $
Poles: $\cos a \pm j\sin a$
The ROC: $z>1$
The system is stable
My question is, is it causal??

Answer (score 1):

The system is **causal**.

Let, $X(z) = \dfrac{z(1-z\cos a)}{z^2-2z\cos a +1} \Rightarrow \dfrac{X(z)}z =  \dfrac{1-z\cos a}{z^2-2z\cos a +1}$

You've found the poles as, $\cos a \pm j \sin a = e^{\pm ja}$.

So let,

$\dfrac{X(z)}{z} =  \dfrac{1-z\cos a}{(z-e^{j a})(z-e^{-ja})} =  \dfrac{k}{z-e^{ja}}+ \dfrac{k^*}{z-e^{-ja}} $

Now by inspection, $k =\dfrac{1-e^{ja}\cos a}{e^{ja} - e^{-ja}} = \dfrac{1- e^{ja}(\frac{e^{ja} + e^{-ja}}{2})}{e^{ja} - e^{-ja}} = -\dfrac{e^{ja}}{2}$

and $k^* = -\dfrac{e^{-ja}}{2}$.

So,

$X(z) = -\dfrac12\left[\dfrac{ze^{ja}}{z-e^{ja}} + \dfrac{ze^{-ja}}{z -e^{-ja}}\right]$

ROC: $|z|>1$ and here $|e^{\pm ja} | = 1$. So clearly, $|z| > |e^{\pm ja}|$.

Thus

$X(z) = -\dfrac12 \mathcal Z\left\{[e^{ja}(e^{jan}) + e^{-ja}e^{-jan}]u(n) \right\} = \mathcal Z \left\{-\cos (an+a)u(n)\right\}$

and the system is causal.

---

For the question now being edited, follow the same partial fraction method. You'll end up getting, $k = k^* = \frac 12$. And it'll reduce to

$$X(z) = \frac{z}{z-e^{ja}}+\frac{z}{z-e^{-ja}} = \mathcal Z \{ \cos (an) u(n) \}$$

This is again causal.

Comment: Thank u so much, it just came to my mind, the ROC>1, is this means it includes the unit circuit?

Comment: No it doesn't include unit circle. You have 2 poles $e^{ja}$ and $e^{-ja}$ each of magnitude 1. ROC doesn't include poles, so it doesn't include the unit circle.